# Add ui-mask directive to another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive for input field which appends calendar icon with datepicker to the input field

I have used this in multiple places in my application now I wanted to add ui-mask which is a directive which I got from angular-ui-mask
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask

But I wanted to add ui-mask to my custom datePicker directive instead of adding ui-mask in multiple places.
How do I add one directive to another directive and make it to work.

I tried adding it in link fn by setting element.attr('ui-mask','99/99/9999') this renders attribute in DOM but doesn't compile.

Please help me with an easy solution for this to work

Comment: Show your code and it's much easier to help

Answer (score 0):

iyou can add template in your directive (path to html/cshtml file).
And in that file write something like:

```
      <div class="test-date-picker">
          <input class="test-date-picker-value" ui-mask="99/99/9999"></input>
     </div>
```

Also please check that you import ui-mask script on your page.